# HTML5/JavaScript/jQuery audio playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this JavaScript/jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
var secondtrack = 'hangover.ogg';
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'hangover.ogg');
audioElement.load()
audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() { 
    audioElement.play(); 
}, true);

$('#play').click(function() {
    audioElement.play();
});
$('#pause').click(function() {
    audioElement.pause();
});
});
```

How could I get another song started after the first ended?

Comment: I don't think this deserves this many downvotes. The question is, are there  events for the `audio` element that allow this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AUDIO element should fire a "ended" event though I am not sure how well this is supported at the moment.

So you could try something like that:

```
audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function () {
    // Play another song
});
```

See also:
http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#event-media-ended